# how to use config file values in .css file in laravel

Tags: css, laravel, config

I want to use Laravel config file values in my .css file to customize some colors how can I do this?
or maybe it is impossible.
I hope my question is clear
Thank you.

my config file

```
return [
'custom' => [
    'mainLayoutType' => 'horizontal',
    'theme' => 'light',
    'sidebarCollapsed' => false,
    'navbarColor' => '',
    'navbarTextColor' => '#ffffff',
],
```

];

my css

```
.header-navbar .navbar-container ul.nav li > a.nav-link {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 1.6rem 1rem 1.35rem 0.5rem;
}
```

what I want to do is something like this

```
.header-navbar .navbar-container ul.nav li > a.nav-link {
  color: config('custom.navbarTextColor');
  padding: 1.6rem 1rem 1.35rem 0.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant add it in a CSS file or even a SCSS file. it has to be a PHP one.

There are two solutions that come to mind

The easy one is to add your css from config in a `<style>` tag in your blade file.

The hard way, is to return a css file via a route (/style.css). something like:

**blade file (css.blade.php)**

```
.header-navbar .navbar-container ul.nav li > a.nav-link {
    color: {{config('custom.navbarTextColor')}};
    padding: 1.6rem 1rem 1.35rem 0.5rem;
}
```

Route line

```
Route::get('/style.css', function() {
    return View::response('css')->header('Content-Type', 'text/css');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I used the first solution @N69D

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically add class to your root html element via php, then write styles in your css according to that.

Example:

```
<body>
  <main class="{{ config('theme') }}">
     ...
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mario for the help